# How to fix vagrant provision errors: inline script, ttyname failed, inapp

Tags: virtualbox, 17.04, vagrant, npm

**Context**: Trying to set up a VM Ethereum development environment on a fresh Ubuntu 17.04 install with the latest versions of Vagrant and VirtualBox installed. More details are [here](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/380#issuecomment-327722141), but the latest attempt at `vagrant up` failed, with what seems like the most important errors being:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "b5460c8c-142b-4dc8-a942-176aee800148", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Could not open the medium'/home/james/VirtualBox VMs/james_default_1504917176677_87192/ubuntu-zesty-17.04-cloudimg.vmdk'.
VBoxManage: error: VMDK: inconsistency between grain table and backup grain table in '/home/james/VirtualBoxV Ms/james_default_1504917176677_87192/ubuntu-zesty-17.04-cloudimg.vmdk' (VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER).
VBoxManage: error: VD: error VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER opening image file '/home/james/VirtualBox VMs/james_default_1504917176677_87192/ubuntu-zesty-17.04-cloudimg.vmdk' (VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
```

Or more succintly, one of the disk files is not accessible (this one: /home/james/VirtualBox VMs/james_default_1504917176677_87192/ubuntu-zesty-17.04-cloudimg.vmdk).

### Further details/troubleshooting

```
$ vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.9.1
```

Vagrant up failed,  I can't run it again and it suggests to run `vagrant provision`.

```
james@james-Streacom:~$ vagrant provision
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
default: Running: inline script
==> default: mesg: 
==> default: ttyname failed
==> default: : 
==> default: Inappropriate ioctl for device
==> default: WARNING: 
==> default: apt
==> default:  
==> default: does not have a stable CLI interface. 
==> default: Use with caution in scripts.
==> default: Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease [89.2 kB]
==> default: Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
==> default: Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease [89.2 kB]
==> default: Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease [89.2 kB]
==> default: Fetched 268 kB in 16s (16.2 kB/s)
==> default: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: 5 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
==> default: WARNING: 
==> default: apt
==> default:  
==> default: does not have a stable CLI interface. 
==> default: Use with caution in scripts.
==> default: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: g++ is already the newest version (4:6.3.0-2ubuntu1).
==> default: make is already the newest version (4.1-9.1).
==> default: python-minimal is already the newest version (2.7.13-2).
==> default: silversearcher-ag is already the newest version (1.0.2-2).
==> default: git is already the newest version (1:2.11.0-2ubuntu0.2).
==> default: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
==> default: --2017-09-09 02:53:39--  https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.3.0/node-v8.3.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
==> default: Resolving nodejs.org (nodejs.org)... 
==> default: 104.20.23.46
==> default: , 
==> default: 104.20.22.46
==> default: Connecting to nodejs.org (nodejs.org)|104.20.23.46|:443... 
==> default: connected.
==> default: HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
==> default: 200 OK
==> default: Length: 
==> default: 11527336
==> default:  (11M)
==> default:  [application/x-xz]
==> default: Saving to: ‘node-v8.3.0-linux-x64.tar.xz.2’
==> default: 
==> default:      0K
```

Followed by many red lines of the loading status, then many more lines of files and sub-folders in:

- node-v8.3.0-linux-x64/
- node-v8.3.0-linux-x64/lib/
- node-v8.3.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/
- node-v8.3.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/
- node-v8.3.0-linux-x64/bin/
- node-v8.3.0-linux-x64/CHANGELOG.md
- node-v8.3.0-linux-x64/include/
- node-v8.3.0-linux-x64/include/node/
- node-v8.3.0-linux-x64/include/node/libplatform/
- node-v8.3.0-linux-x64/include/node/openssl/
- node-v8.3.0-linux-x64/share/

Then finally the output ended with:

```
==> default: mv: 
==> default: cannot move 'node-v8.3.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules' to '/usr/lib/node_modules'
==> default: : Directory not empty
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

I considered deleting `/usr/lib/node_modules` and running `vagrant provision` again, but I haven't yet. Instead I tried `vagrant reload`.

```
james@james-Streacom:~$ vagrant reload
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/zesty64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "b5460c8c-142b-4dc8-a942-176aee800148", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Could not open the medium'/home/james/VirtualBox VMs/james_default_1504917176677_87192/ubuntu-zesty-17.04-cloudimg.vmdk'.
VBoxManage: error: VMDK: inconsistency between grain table and backup grain table in '/home/james/VirtualBoxV Ms/james_default_1504917176677_87192/ubuntu-zesty-17.04-cloudimg.vmdk' (VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER).
VBoxManage: error: VD: error VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER opening image file '/home/james/VirtualBox VMs/james_default_1504917176677_87192/ubuntu-zesty-17.04-cloudimg.vmdk' (VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
```

When I opened Virtual Box I got the error message:

> One or more disk image files are not currently accessible. As a result, you will not be able to operate virtual machines that use these files until they become accessible later.
>   Press Check to open the Virtual Media Manager window and see which files are inaccessible, or press Ignore to ignore this message.

**Related**: https://serverfault.com/questions/324271/virtualbox-grain-table-inconsistency#575058

I manually deleted the folders in the files app: VirtualBox VMs, .vagrant, and .vagrantd, and the `vagrantfile`. Then, I ran `vagrant init`, edited the `vagrantfile` to be like this one [here](https://github.com/jwasinger/ethereum-dev-env/blob/master/ethereumjs/Vagrantfile), except with zesty rather than trusty, then ran `vagrant up`.

While the previously mentioned files loaded (in green), the ouput ended (in red) with:

```
==> default: cp: 
==> default: cannot stat '/vagrant/.tmux.conf'
==> default: : No such file or directory
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Posting here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/6YCXpBJmhsM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to clone the directory here: https://github.com/jwasinger/ethereum-dev-env, then navigate to the folder in that directory in the terminal with the vagrantfile, and run `vagrant up`. The gateway of my router doesn't have SSH enabled, so I need to do that.